# Is it possible to store the same ( equal ) key data in redis?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to store the same ( equal ) key data in redis? I've 2 different data have the same ( equal ) key, can I store it in Redis?

Comment: You can save it in HASH, with the same key name, but different field name.

Comment: Can you please add more details about your use case? Why would you like to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the fields are different.

Redis is a [key/value database](https://redis.com/nosql/key-value-databases/) which by definition typically means that there cannot be two different entries with the same key as a keys correspond to a particular value.

A way to sort of have two different values have the same key is to distinguish them by having different fields. This can be done by using [`HSET`](https://redis.io/commands/hset/). An example of this is below.

```
> HSET key field1 value1
> HSET key field2 value2
```

The above two values `value1` and `value2` have the same key, `key`, but they are distinguished by different field values.